# Mojolicious External References Not working on only one page

Tags: javascript, mojolicious

Please let me know if there are more code or errors that would be helpful.

My issue is that I have external JS files and all of my pages can find them accept for one. When I go to my "User" section I get a 404 for each external file. Also it looks like it requests each one twice?

I have my external JS in the public folder. I also have my references in the main layout that each page shares.

I'm at a complete loss as to what this could be...

My default layout contains.

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./search.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./employee_information.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./requests.js"></script>
</head>
```

In my public folder I have (employee_information.js, requests.js, and search.js)

Each of my navbar links are asa follows

```
   %= link_to 'Home' => 'phone_book_form'
   %= link_to 'Users' => 'user_index'
   %= link_to 'Account' => 'account_details'
```

My paths are as follows

```
$r->get('/')->name('phone_book_form')->to('PhoneBook#form');
  $admin_authorized->get('/user_list')->name('user_index')->to('User#index');
  $authorized->get('/account_details')->name('account_details')->to('Account#details');
```

Only my User Index page can't find the external js.

In Firefox Developer tools

I get a 200 initially, then on the next i get a 304 , then On my User Index page I get 6 404s.

I think I found the issue...
[image]

Any direction is much appreciated.

Comment: tags for perl, javascript, ajax, exteral, mojolious, when 99% of the tags are not relevant to the question

Comment: I'm using perl with mojolicious, my external files are js that hold my ajax commands. I'm sorry what would be more appropriate tags?

Comment: but 99% of them are not related to the problem, the tags should relate the problem, not everything you use. Please also add the page code where you are having issues, it is not possible to point out your error without code.

Comment: So just a javascript tag? I will add the portions now.

Comment: What might be useful is the output of `tree` or a screenshot of a Windows Explorer showing where the files are exactly, and which files cannot be found. Are you running this with `morbo` or in production with `hypnotoad` or another server? If the files are served by Mojo, include the log messages of the files that are not found please. You can [edit] your question to add the clarification.

Comment: You do not need the ajax tag. It's not relevant if the file contains ajax stuff, plain JS, or spaghetti. Your problem is that the file seems to be not there. Keep the question simple, that will make it easier to understand.

Comment: I will add a screen shot. Okay I understand sorry about that. And I am using Daemon server as I am running on windows (No hypnotoad )

Comment: I see you actually found it yourself. :)

Comment: You all pointed me in the right direction  though ;)

Comment: Retracted my downvote after the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your javascript files are referenced in a relative way, because you start the paths with `./`.

When you are on the route `/` (i.e. http://localhost:3000/), that works fine, because `./search.js` starting at `/` is http://localhost:3000/search.js. But when you are on the `/user_list` route (i.e. http://localhost:3000/user_list), your `./` is now in `/user_list`, so it's looking for a file http://localhost:3000/user_list/search.js. The webserver now looks for the file `user_list/search.js` in the `public` folder, but that doesn't exist, so it renders a 404 error.

```
                                      | here 
<head>                                V
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./search.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./user_information.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./requests.js"></script>
</head>
```

Instead, use absolute paths starting at the root directory `/`. So the URIs should be:

```
/search.js
/user_information.js
/request.js
```

Comment: Sure enough. Thank you for your patience and help.